# pros and cons of creating a object in java with different approaches

Tags: java

As i am a java developer basically engage in coding specially at development level as i was exploring the ways to create a object in java , till now i have discovered the following ways to create the object in java but now can you please advise the pros and cons of each way and which particular way we should choose under which scenario ...

- Using new keyword This is the most common way to create an object in
  java. I read somewhere that almost 99% of objects are created in this
  way.

`MyObject object = new MyObject();`

- Using Class.forName() If we know the name of the class & if it has a
  public default constructor we can create an object in this way.

`MyObject object = (MyObject) Class.forName("subin.rnd.MyObject").newInstance();`

- Using clone() The clone() can be used to create a copy of an existing
  object

`MyObject anotherObject = new MyObject();`

`MyObject object = anotherObject.clone();`

- Using object deserialization Object deserialization is nothing but
  creating an object from its serialized form.

`ObjectInputStream inStream = new ObjectInputStream(anInputStream );`

`MyObject object = (MyObject) inStream.readObject();`

Comment: you wrote the meaning of each line yourself! so what's your question?

Comment: Please take the time to use the wide array of formatting tools on the formatting toolbar and/or read the big orange **How to Format** box that was next to the text area when you were typing your question, and use the preview that appears underneath it.

Comment: #2 is just wrong. `Class.forName` doesn't create an instances, it loads the class. No instance constructor is called unless the class has static initializers that set up instances of things.

Answer (score 1):

Each way below has different and specific purpose.  See below

*1 Using new keyword*

MyObject object = new MyObject();

```
 This is the way you create the object in java when you know which object to create.
```

*2 Using Class.forName()*
MyObject object = (MyObject) Class.forName("subin.rnd.MyObject").newInstance();

```
This is the way you create the object in java when you don't know which object to create in advance.I mean object that needs to be created comes from DB or property file
```

*3 Using clone()*

MyObject anotherObject = new MyObject();

MyObject object = anotherObject.clone();

```
This is the way when you need to create the copy of existing object
```

*4 Using object deserialization*

Object deserialization is nothing but reconstructing an object from its serialized form.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by persist the state of object to reconstruct it later?  Object deserialization is effectively the same end result as cloning is it not?

Comment: @RSchultz i did the minor correction. Actually i earlier explained the serialization process instead of desrialization